# why no whole width of screen is covered?

Tags: javascript, css, width

I use css and JavaScript to lock screen, but I am not sure why the lock panel is not the same width as screen, do you have any idea?
Here is HTML source and you find javascript code as below, does anyone help me?

JavaScript:

```
function FreezeScreen(msg) {
    scroll(0,0);
    var outerPane = document.getElementById('FreezePane');
    var innerPane = document.getElementById('InnerFreezePane');
    if (outerPane) outerPane.className = 'FreezePaneOn';
    if (innerPane) innerPane.innerHTML = msg;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div align="center" id="FreezePane" class="FreezePaneOff">
   <div id="InnerFreezePane" class="InnerFreezePane"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.FreezePaneOff {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

.FreezePaneOn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 999;
  filter:alpha(opacity=85);
  -moz-opacity:0.85;
  padding-top: 20%;
}

.InnerFreezePane {
  text-align: center;
  width: 66%;
  background-color: #171;
  color: White;
  font-size: large;
  border: dashed 2px #111;
  padding: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: Try using `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw`

Comment: it will be the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my quetion by two ways, Method2 is not good because fixed width, but I am not sure why Method1 is ok, does anyone explain to me?

Method1:

```
.FreezePaneOn {
  ...
  width: 103%;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

Method2:

```
.FreezePaneOn {
  ...
  width: 990px;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to cover the screen you could change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`

> Position property :
>
> **absolute** - The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
>   (not static) ancestor element.
>
> **fixed** - The element is positioned relative to the browser window.

Comment: The html and css you've provided above work (once FreezePaneOff is changed to FreezePaneOn) but that is in isolation. There must be something else in your code that is making behave unexpectedly. It might be invalid markup, or some of css properties being unintentinally applied to your freezePane div. You'll need to provide more of your html and css.

Comment: I call `FreezeScreen("Locking...");` to lock screen.

Comment: By the way, I am using frame